# Unwanted super thick borders in Xubuntu 15.10

Tags: xorg, gtk, gtk3, 15.10

I have recently updated to Ubuntu (Xubuntu) 15.10. After this update, I see super thick borders around some windows. This seem to plague only Gtk+ applications:

[image: thick borders]

Why? Can I fix it?

Note: I do not have any local themes installed - i.e. no themes in ~/.themes

**UPDATE**

I have submitted a bug report against Ubuntu: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1520435